# try block giving compilation error

Tags: java, try-catch

I am trying to use try block for my code, but it gives compilation error. Code is :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        { 
             //my logic goes here
            return; 
        } 
    }
```

Please help solving problem.

Comment: You need to add in a catch block }catch (exception e){//handle ..error}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try block can not be used without catch/finally block.

your code should be like :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        { 
            //mu logic goes here
            return; 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }    
    }
```

or

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        { 
                //mu logic goes here
            return; 
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

or it can have both multiple catch but only one finally in any combinations.

[refer to java docs for basic learning of try-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

Comment: @Robin, finally would be hit in any case, expect if JVM terminates.

Comment: I read it somewhere, never tried it before until now. @Batty you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Most basic correct form. This will catch any error and print out the error message.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        { 
         //my logic goes here

        }
        catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println(e);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

catch with try or finally is mandatory, please refer to below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try 
    { 
         //my logic goes here
        return; 
    } catch(Exception e){
      // Do Something
    }
}


  public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try 
    { 
         //my logic goes here
        return; 
    } finally{
      // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: _catch with try or finally is mandatory_ did you mean that _try_ with _catch_ or _finally_ is mandatory?

Comment: yes, as per java semantics try should be followed by either catch/ finally. Also this holds true till jdk 1.6, with jdk 1.7 Resource handling feature semantics has changed somewhat.

Comment: I know that, my comment was on how the sentence is written. _catch with try or finally is mandatory_ Means "you must use a catch/try or catch/finally" to me, which is not correct.